# Text over image. I can't seem to get my text over my picture. I tried with absolution and everything.

Tags: html, css, text

Text over image. I can't seem to get my text over my picture. I tried with absolution and everything.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="stages col col-6">
            <a href="..\stage1\index.html" title="Stage 1"><img src="styles\images\stage1.jpg" alt="Stage1"></a>
            <p>Stage 1</p>
            </div>

        <div class="stages col col-6">
        <a href="..\stage2\index.html" title="Stage 2"><img src="styles\images\stage2.jpg" alt="Stage2"></a>
        <p>Stage 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your CSS, what you have tried so far.

Comment: CSS may have faults but absolution is not usually required. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolution

Answer (score 2):

You are not applying it correctly.

To make it work, you need to make the parent `div` to have a `position:relative;` and the child div to have `position:absolute;`

Once you do the `position:absolute;`, you need to change the positioning by attributes such as `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` with numeric values.

Just in case, if your text is below the image, you can use `z-index` attribute to bring it up with a numeric value.

**For Instance,**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="position:relative;">
            <div class="stages col col-6">
            <a href="..\stage1\index.html" title="Stage 1"><img src="styles\images\stage1.jpg" alt="Stage1"></a>
            <p style="position:absolute;top: 0;left: 0;">Stage 1</p>
            </div>

        <div class="stages col col-6">
        <a href="..\stage2\index.html" title="Stage 2"><img src="styles\images\stage2.jpg" alt="Stage2"></a>
        <p>Stage 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/025aj1s5/)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to manage it through classes. Add `image-container` to the parent div of image, and `text-over-img` to p tag used for text.

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
}

.text-over-img {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mwr2wxpk/)